# How to find only exact results in a point of interest search?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Map Api for geocoding a map module for real estates. I'd like display features (POI) like schools, bus station, Rer, Metro, tramway, creche, colleges, etc.

I tried to use many functions like `nearbySearch` and `radarSearch`, but thoses functions results in lots of points that are not Schools, like for example a bus station that is named "School station".

How to find the real results doing difference between, colleges, primary schools, universitys, etc.?

Here is my code:

```
function performSearch(checked, type){
    if(checked){
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch({
            location: map.getCenter(),
            radius: 5000,
            name: type
        }, callback);
    } else{
        for (var i = 0; i < poisMarkers.length; i++) {
            poisMarkers[i].setMap(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some of your source code to help you

Comment: Maybe you should use [type filter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) in your request instead of name. You can find a list of supported types here: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Comment: I already tryed to use this, but like I said, it results all schools and I would like to display only lycee or college. Is there a way to combine two types to get exactly what I need ?